# How to avoid redundant nested divs using Styled Components

Tags: css, styled-components

I have several components used to build layouts. For example, a Row, a Column, and a Vertical Align component:

```
export const Row = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;

  > * {
    margin-left: 10px;
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
`

export const Column = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
`

export const VerticalAlign = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
`
```

Using them together produces unnecessary nested divs:

```
<Row>
  <Column>
    <VerticalAlign>
      <Icon />
      <input />
    </VerticalAlign>
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <VerticalAlign>
      // ...
    </VerticalAlign>
  </Column>
</Row>
```

If this were just css, I would do this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column vertical-align">
    // ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I could extend classes, but that would create an explosion of one-off components for every combination:

```
const VerticalAlignColumn = styled(Column)`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
`;

const VerticalAlignRow = styled(Row)`
  //...
`;
```

Is there a way to easily combine the styles of multiple components into a single component? Something like `<Row+VerticalAlign>...</Row+VerticalAlign>`?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to do like you want.

And the best approach here is like you said (created extend classes) or work with props, like this:

```js
export const Column = styled.div`
  flex: 1;

  ${({ verticalAlign }) =>
    verticalAlign &&
    `
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  `}
`;

<Column verticalAlign>
   <Icon />
   <input />
</Column>
<Column>
   <Icon />
   <input />
</Column>
```

You can also work with classes, but it has some specificities -> [Styling normal React components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#issues-with-specificity)